# How to apply CSS styles to my <Loader /> React component?

Tags: css, typescript, materialize, conditional-operator, react-component

I have a code for my button written for my **React web application**. There i have a ternary operator which shows **Loader** if it loads and shows **children** if it is loaded. I'm using **Materialize CSS library** to add some button styles for it but it doesn't work and i don't know why please help me.

```
export const DeprecatedButtonWithLoading: FC<
    {
        readonly isLoading: boolean
    } & DeprecatedButtonProps
> = ({ isLoading, children, ...buttonProps }) => {
    return (
        <DeprecatedButton {...buttonProps}>
            {isLoading ? <Loader /> : children }
        </DeprecatedButton>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on does `Loader` provide such API.

I couldnt find `Loader` in Materialize docs, so I suppose `Loader` is your handwritten component. In this case you can find your `Loader` component, add there `style` property and forward it to its container. For example

```
const Loader = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={props.style}>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But. If `Loader` is foreign component then you should check docs in place where did you get it.